# HTML rendering issue and extra tag being rendered

Tags: html, css

can anyone tell me why my site at www.castawayministries.com/new looks like it does when on mobile or desktop but viewing the files locally directly from VSCode it looks great till its uploaded to my actual webhosting server?
weird thing is above the facebook font-awesome icon theres a div with a class of header-top-sw that appears after uploading to hosting server but it is no where in my code in VSCode. Looked everywhere for it. can't find it.

I even copied the code from the site when viewing it from my server at link above and pasted it into my document and took out that one div tag with the above header-top-sw manually, resaved my document and reuploaded it and still shows up somehow. And is still broken.

a link

i expected it to render and not add an extra div tag

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-4 header-top-sw"> 
  <div class="col-4 header-top-social"> 
      <ul> 
        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      </ul> 
    </div> <!-- END .col-4 --> 
  <div class="col-8 header-top-arearight">Section 2</div> <!-- END .col-8 --> 
</div> <!-- END .row -->
```

Comment: Can you please create a snippet so we can see what you've done? **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: This is what I see **[here](http://prntscr.com/lx3t60)**

Comment: here is a snippet of just the section with added div tag but to get all my code you can look at http://castawayministries.com/new/

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-4 header-top-sw">
     <div class="col-4 header-top-social">
      <ul>
       <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <!-- END .col-4 -->
     <div class="col-8 header-top-arearight">Section 2</div>
     <!-- END .col-8 -->
    </div>
    <!-- END .row -->

Comment: he's talking about putting the code up in something like a codepen.com or maybe in this case, it would be more suitable for a link to Github so we can see the full project

Comment: url typed wrong. Its http://castawayministries.com/new/

Comment: ok ill add to github. will take a minute

Comment: I already added it. Just wait. It has to be peer reviewed.

Comment: github link here --> https://github.com/mjohnson24/CastawayMinistriesNew

Comment: @webfrogs what did you already add that has to be peer reviewed?

Comment: sorry guys this is just my first time on stackoverflow so getting use to it and github as well. Still very green and rusty with github and all.

Comment: All good. I started posting my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of your issue...
Your columns should total 12. You have 4 | 4 | 8

Your first column is also unclosed

**Your snippet**

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-4 header-top-sw"> 
  <div class="col-4 header-top-social"> 
      <ul> 
        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      </ul> 
    </div> <!-- END .col-4 --> 
  <div class="col-8 header-top-arearight">Section 2</div> <!-- END .col-8 --> 
</div> <!-- END .row -->
```

**How it should be**

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4 header-top-sw">Section 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 header-top-social"> 
      <ul> 
        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      </ul> 
    </div> <!-- END .col-4 --> 
  <div class="col-md-4 header-top-arearight">Section 2</div>
</div>
```

Also, your comments made it look confusing, so I pulled them out for now.

Additionally, look at **[this](http://prntscr.com/lx3wtc)** - You have an open script tag with nothing in it.

Also, put your jquery at the bottom of your page, just above your bootstrap script.

Comment: heres the issue with that though. The page im uploading has all the missing tags at the bottom that you are mentioning and the extra div tag for <div class="col-md-4 header-top-sw"> is not in my code in VSCode

Comment: my github i linked to has my exact code in it thats in my VSCode as well. what you see in github is whats in VSCode.

https://github.com/mjohnson24/CastawayMinistriesNew

Comment: I see your code on github. I don't see that first col-4. First, I'd make sure you're browser isn't caching. Then, double-check to make sure you're uploading the code to your server correctly, and that it's the right file. You left that snippet in there somewhere and that's likely what's happening.

Comment: Also, your page set up is off. I've redone your page, based on your code. View **[codepen here](https://codepen.io/newnam/full/GPNbQd)**

Comment: no page isn't cached in browser cause it happens across all computers Mac/pc im testing it on and on my phone that i just tested it on for the first time. As far as uploading it correctly im uploading it to my server via filezilla just like i have always done all my sites in the past with no issues so its uploading correctly or it should be for sure and its the correct file for sure.

Comment: Your navbar was opening behind the slider, which didn't make sense. Also, on your website, the slider images were stacked because of where your jquery script was located. There were a few small things. 

You can use a site like [diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) and run my do-over with your code and see the differences.

Comment: yea i see the col-4 etc tags changed to col-md-X, container above nav changed to container-fluid as well as adding p-0 and m-0 along with it. I also see "fa fa-facebook-square" was changed to "fab fa-facebook-square". Minus a few aria changes and such. whats the fab tag on facebook icon do and whats the p-0 and m-0 classes do? I think that was about the only changes that was different but it does break my code when copying your code and overwriting mine. It starts to look like it does when its live now

Comment: i just uploaded my code to https://secure.ohmserv.com/CastawayMinistries/index.html and it looks like its suppose to. my guess is hostgator is doing something so guess ill have to get with them in it.

Comment: We got to the bottom of it then. Please mark the answer correct.